# Maven/gradle peerDependency

Tags: maven, gradle

In npm I can use a `peerDependency`; a requirement on the requesting library to provide an implementation of the required `peerDependency`. Is there something like this in maven/gradle?

I have a plugin library with AST transformations for Entities, it adds a java8 `dateCreated` and `lastUpdated` field to the entities. 
Hibernate has a support library for these classes;

```
org.hibernate:hibernate-java8:<hibernate_version>
```

I can't add this as a `runtime` dependency to my plugin, because I don't know which `<hibernate_version>` is in use. So I like to express a `peerDependency` (or whatever the maven alternative is called) for `org.hibernate:hibernate-java8:[lower-upper]`. Is this possible?

Comment: I doubt that this is possible but I would be glad to get to know the converse.

Comment: In Maven, does either [`<scope>provided</scope>`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) or declaring the dependency as [`<optional>true</optional>`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) do what you need?